# UILabel on Multi gesture view

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a third party view from a framework with multiple touch gestures and I want to add a UILabel on top that handles a single tap event. For some reason, the touch event on the UILabel does not work when it is a subview of the third party view, but when I switch the view to a normal UIView it works as intended. Here I make the label:

```
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 40);
  UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"label"];
  label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                      action:@selector(labelTapped:)];
  singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  [label addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: Not trying to be flippant, but what you're describing you want is a UIButton.  You can program a button with similar behavior, or you can have your label and put an invisible (clear) button on top, and that will probably make your programming easier.

Comment: It may be happening because all touch events are being received by parent view. @OwenHartnett is right. You should try using `UIButton` of custom type. It will work for you like hyperlink.